# Port forwarding killing the springboard server?

Tags: ssh, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am trying port-forwarding from `Local machine` ->`EC2` ->`RDS`

What I am doing is like this on local machine

```
$ssh -f -N -L 3308:my_rds.amazonaws.com:3306 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.cina02 ubuntu@my_ec2.amazonaws.com

$mysqldump -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3308 -pXXXXXX -v mydb > mybackup.sql
```

It will dump more than 9GB file. When doing this, somehow my EC2 server gets stuck, and `mysqldump` command is also stuck.

And finally it doesn't accept even `ssh`, so I need to restart `EC2`. In my understanding. `mysqldump` is working in my localhost.

Why does the springboard server(ie, the EC2 instance) stop responding?. Yellow line is CPU usage on CloudWatch

[image]

Comment: What instance type is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my understanding. mysqldump is working in my localhost.

```
ssh -f -N -L 3308:my_rds.amazonaws.com:3306
```

You're doing local port forwarding. You're running mysqldump on your local computer which is [bound to the remote host](http://dirk-loss.de/ssh-port-forwarding.htm) and the mysqldump is running on local. However, as evident by the CPU utilization spike, this is most likely because of the network tunnel that the  EC2 has to maintain and the data that is being pushed through the tunnel. If you're running a burst-class instance, ie the T-type, it is quite likely that you're exhausting your CPU credits quota and as a result AWS is throttling the CPU, resulting in poor response.

See [AWS docs for more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html).

Comment: so, basically, I was wrong. thank you very much. Is it impossible to use `mysqldump` on local machine for RDS via EC2? or is there any method? because in my case, only EC2 has the access to RDS and EC2 doesn't have the enough power to execute mysqldump.

Comment: However , this is another question. you gave me the great hint. thank you very much I accepted your answer.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: thank you for editing. mmm it is a bit difficult for me. `mysqldump` is running on local but it bound to the remote host...  My plan is `t3.xlarge` , it is a burst-class as you told. however I have no privilege to change the EC2 plan.